# REST web Service to consume PDF in Binary Form from external System

Tags: apex, rest, pdf, web

I have a requirement where external system  will be posting PDF to salesfore in binary form as REST Post call and I need to cosume the PDF to attach it to the Object as attachments.

Following is my webservice code:

```
@RestResource(urlMapping = '/PDF/')
    global class PDF {
    
        @httpPost
        global static void createsamplePDF() {
            RestRequest req = RestContext.request;
            Blob body = req.requestBody;
            ContentVersion cv = new ContentVersion(VersionData =body);
            insert cv;
        }
        
    }
```

Also As I am getting Request so getResponseAsBlob method of HttpResponse would not be applicable in my case I guess. Is there any method equivalent for HttpRequest also for this purpose.

I am getting error reading PDF from this service as it's not getting generated successfully. Please suggest any alternative approach if possible.

Thanks

Comment: Are you sending the base64 encoded string as the body for the service?

Comment: Also try setting the content-type to application/pdf

Comment: @MohithShrivastava thanks for reply. External system will be calling this salesfoece webservice and passing pdf as binary form. This is post call from external system to salesforce. And I want to generate pdf after reading this binary string and attach it as attachment to my record in salesforce

Comment: This is an [X-Y Problem](https://xyproblem.info/). I would argue that the best solution would be to use the native [Blob](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/dome_sobject_insert_update_blob.htm) REST API. If you absolutely insist on Apex, though, you'll be limiting yourself to <6MB files at best. We'd need to see a sample payload to understand why your Apex isn't working, either.

Comment: @sfdxfox. Thanks for the reply. Let me try with Blob native REST API. and also let me paste sample payload.

Answer (score 0):

> As @sfdcfox mentioned, with this custom API you will be limiting yourself to <6MB files due to Apex Heap Size Limit.

You can retrieve the body as a Blob from the HttpRequest object as `RestContext.request.requestBody`. With the blob you need to Create `ContentVersion` and `ContentDocumentLink` to attach the file to a Record.

You cannot define parameters to the Apex method and return type of the method should be void. You can use URL parameters to get the File Name, Object Id etc. In the below example I am getting the Record Id to attach the file. Use Exception Handling to handle any errors. You can use a wrapper class to send a detailed response.

```
@RestResource(urlMapping='/v1/PDF/*')
global without sharing class PDFRestResource {
    @httpPost
    global static void createSamplePDF() {
        String objId = RestContext.request.params.get('objId');//Pass the Salesforce Id of the Record in the URL
        
        //Insert ContentVersion
        ContentVersion cv = new ContentVersion();
        cv.PathOnClient = 'sample.pdf';//File name with extension
        cv.Title = 'Sample PDF';//Name of the file
        cv.VersionData = RestContext.request.requestBody;//File content fro the Request
        Insert cv;
        
        //get the ContentDocumentId
        Id cd = [SELECT ContentDocumentId FROM ContentVersion WHERE Id =:cv.Id].ContentDocumentId;
        
        //Insert ContentDocumentLink
        ContentDocumentLink cdl = new ContentDocumentLink();
        cdl.ContentDocumentId = cd;// ContentDocumentId received from the SOQL Query
        cdl.LinkedEntityId = objId;//Add attachment to the Object
        Insert cdl;
        
        RestContext.response.addHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        RestContext.response.responseBody = Blob.valueOf('File uploaded successfully');        
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you @Saroj Bera for detailed reply.